# Aggreggate and transpone one dataframe based on 2 columns GroupBy Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

Good evening! I have a dataframe with columns "dialog_id", "type" and "message". Each row on the df is basically one message description. I want to group this df, so it would show me how many messages of each type each dialog_id had sent. dialog_id is in strings, message is int(it's just a column of 1).
So, what do I have now:

| dialog_id| message  |type |
| -------- | -------- |------
| name1    |     1    |video|
| name1    |      1   |text |
| name2    |    1     |audio|
2)What I want to achive(expected output). Here 1 row is a describtion of one dialog_id, not message

| dialog_id | video | text | *more types* | total sent messages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | 15 | 20 | x | 35+x |
| name2 | 17 | 3 | y | 20+y |

Main problem is counting each type for each dialog.Groupby counts either each dialog or each type

```
aggregation_functions = {'message': 'sum', 'type': 'first', 'dialog_id':'first'}
df_n = df_var.groupby('dialog_id').aggregate(aggregation_functions)
```

but this and other variatons don't really work. Please help

Comment: So need first merge both DataFrames? and then aggreagate? What is expected ouput?

Comment: @jezrael
There is only one dataframe(first table), expected output is the second table(where each row is a describtion of dialog_id)

Comment: Not understand, I cannot see data from `df1` possible convert to `df2`, e.g. in df1 not exist `video=15,17`

Comment: in another words df1 not match with df2 ouput.

Comment: @jezrael no, video 15,17 it is count. So, for example I have 15 video messages from one person, in initial dataframe it is stored like 15 rows of "message": "1", "type":"video", I want to sum them so there is only one such row, presenting amount

Comment: Try `pd.crosstab(df_var['dialog_id'], df_var['type']).assign(**{'total sent messages': lambda x: x.sum(axis=1)})`